# Ability to create new File Templates in Flash Builder 4

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flexunit

I have a class interface that I have written in a Flex project using ActionScript 3 .  I write FlexUnit test cases around each implementation of that interface.  To help the process of creating new ones, I thought it would nice to create a FlexUnit file template around my interface.

Is there a way to create new FlexUnit file templates?  It seems as though you can only modify the default templates.

If anyone has an idea on how to do that or a reference link, please let me know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to try [SourceMate 2.0](http://elementriver.com/sourcemate) which supports custom file templates or wait for Flash Builder 4.5 which supports them too.

Comment: I was checking this post out and wanted to add an update.  Flash Builder 4.5.1 allows you to edit current templates and then subsequently save as new ones.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is still 'no' in Flash Builder 4.6.  The Adobe documentation mentions *Customize* for File Templates but no information on adding or removing user defines File Templates.

Even after exporting existing File Templates, altering the XML and importing them in Flash Builder I was never able to get the application to show a new File Template. It would only alter existing templates with the same 'ID' attribute.  In addition there is no UI in Flash Builder's File Template view to remove a user created template.

[Customize file templates](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5344c6f711358acdda1d-7fff.html#WSe4e4b720da9dedb56fd3caca12e6bb494bb-7fef)

I bug is filed the Adobe JIRA website: FB-33340.